# Check if value has a given character - RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to check if an `input` with the `type=number` contains the character `-`.
Can someone help me with the RegEx expression?

Comment: Why regex? Just use string methods

Comment: `String.indexOf("-");`...or `/.*-.*/`.

Comment: The problem is that you won't be able to read the string entered by the user. Since `-` is an invalid character in a floating-point number, if you use `.value` you will get the empty string. Better use `type="text"`.

Comment: the problem is that i can check if it has '-' but when user deletes input's content by backspace it returns null and also it does if it contains '-', and those are 2 different cases.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just apply the following expression:

```
^[-\d]+$
```

This will only allow digits and a dash in the input.
*Btw, no need for the anchors in HTML5 directly (they are anchored by default).*